# Jenkins MSBuild Process cannot access the file

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

In my Jenkins build workflow I am using MSBuild to build project and then run publish profile to deploy files. General Setup below:

> **Build a Visual Studo project or solution using MSBuild**
>
> **MSBuild Version:**
>
> MSBuild VS2017
>
> **MSBuild Build File:**
>
> ProjectName.csproj
>
> **Command Line Arguments:**
>
> /P:DeployOnBuild=True
>
> /P:PublishProfile=profile-name
>
> /P:Configuration=config-name

Issue I am running into is during the publishing process it is throwing, "*The process cannot access the file ________ because it is being used by another process.*":

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(96,5):
>   error : Copying file
>   obj\jenkins-services-cms\Package\PackageTmp\bin\FileName.dll to
>   \server\bin\FileName.dll failed. The process cannot access the file
>   '\server\bin\FileName.dll' because it is being used by another
>   process. [D:\jenkins\workspace\WorkspaceName\ProjectName.csproj]

Manually scheduling another build in Jenkins typically resolves the build error. Is there any way to apply permissions during the publishing process to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Jenkins MSBuild Process cannot access the file

According to the error message "*The process cannot access the file '\server\bin\FileName.dll' because it is being used by another process.* ". It seems you do not have write permission to the folder `server`.

You can try to Set write permission by `.wpp.targets` file on the that folder, for details info, you can refer to the document: [Setting Folder Permissions on Web Publish](http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/SettingFolderPermissionsOnWebPublish.aspx)

If above not help you, please try to use Process Explorer to find out what is holding on that file/folder, and make sure you have close all Visual Studio instance, and you can try to kill the handle.